# How to create a generic Collection<T> at runtime?

Tags: java, generics

I'm writing a method which filters a specific Collection with a "Predicate" and returns a new Collection containing only filtered elements (those for whom Predicate returns true).

Something like this :

```
    public <T> Collection<T> filter(Collection<T> collection, Closure<T> predicate);
```

I know that, in Java, I can't just create a new `Collection()` at runtime, because of type-erasure.

I also know the "work-around" by passing an extra-argument to the method to call T.newInstance().

This would look like :

```
    public <T> Collection<T> filter(Class<? extends Collection<T>> collectionToInstanciate, Collection<T> collection, Closure<T> predicate) {

        // create the new Collection
        Collection<T> container = collectionToInstanciate.newInstance();

        // and then add only filtered items
        Iterator<T> iter = collection.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            T obj = iter.next();

            // if Predicate.invoke() returns true, then keep element, otherwise skip it
            if (predicate.invoke(obj)) {
                container.add(obj);
            }
        }
        return container;
    }
```

But how should I call my method ?

For instance, if I want only odd numbers of a List of Integers, I'd like to do :

```
    // instanciate ArrayList<Integer> = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    ArrayList<Integer> array = ...;

    // return a new LinkedList<Integer> with only odd numbers
    filter(LinkedList<Integer>.class, array, new Closure<Integer>() {
        public Boolean invoke(Integer arg_p) {
            return (arg_p % 2 == 0);
        }
    });

    // should return [2, 4] as a LinkedList<Integer>
```

The problem is that

```
    LinkedList<Integer>.class
```

doesn't compile.

How should I declare that to correctly instanciate a LinkedList in the filter() method ?

Regards,

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but cannot you pass MyClass.class and use it as a LinkedList parameter inside the method?

Comment: Note that `Collection` is an interface, not a class. By the way, due to type erasure, you should use the raw class, not the parameterized way i.e. `LinkedList.class` instead of `LinkedList<Whatever>.class`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza : using LinkedList.class instead of LinkedList<Whatever>.class was actually my problem : I don't want to instanciate a "raw" LinkedList in the filter() method, so I'll get with Peter Lawrey's solution. thanks

Comment: @Quirin : yes of course, but I wanted to write a more generic filter() method, in which you can return the filtered Collection created from any Java Collection (Set<T>, ArrayList<T>, etc...), not just LinkedList

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generics are a compile time feature and have little meaning at runtime.  If you want to create a LinkedList, that is what you do.  You can't make the compiler give you an error based on something you do at runtime.

A simpler solution is to pass an instance of the class you want to populate.

```
List<Integer> result = filter(new LinkedList<Integer>(), array, 
    new Predicate<Integer>() {
        public boolean invoke(Integer arg_p) {
            return (arg_p % 2 == 0);
        }
    });
```

It is marginally shorter and can be checked at compile time.

Note: many of these predicates are much simpler and faster as a plain loop.

```
List<Integer> result = new LinkedList<Integer>();
for(Integer i: array)
    if (i % 2 == 0)
        result.add(i);
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. I hoped generics would have been more powerful, but because of type-erasure, I just can't write a "C++-style" template :(

Comment: @adrien.pain Java tends to err on the side of simplicity over power of expression.  It does mean it's easier to read other people's code as there is less opportunity for edge cases, and different ways of writing the same thing.

Comment: yes i agree with that. But I don't like type-erasure at all ;-)

Comment: @adrien.pain Type-erasure is sometime which has added to have a minimum of changes in the JVM.  I believe if it were done today, Oracle would not have placed such a restriction on the design.

Answer (score 0):

Another way around, from Peter Lawrey's answer and LuiggiMendoza's comment, is to use the filter() method this way :

```
    List<Integer> result = filter(
        LinkedList.class, // instead of new LinkedList<Integer>()
        array, 
        new Predicate<Integer>() {
            public boolean invoke(Integer arg_p) {
                return (arg_p % 2 == 0);
            }
        });
```

And in the filter() method :

```
    public <T> Collection<T> filter(Class<? extends Collection> collectionToInstanciate, Collection<T> collection, Closure<T> predicate) {

    // create the new Collection as a raw Collection, and cast it back to Collection<T>
    Collection<T> container = (Collection<T>) collectionToInstanciate.newInstance();

    // and then add only filtered items
    Iterator<T> iter = collection.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        T obj = iter.next();

        // if Predicate.invoke() returns true, then keep element, otherwise skip it
        if (predicate.invoke(obj)) {
            container.add(obj);
        }
    }
    return container;
}
```

Comment: I can imagine this approach failing pretty badly for Collection implementations that don't have 0-arg constructors.  You can include a factory parameter instead to avoid all this gratuitous reflection, and define a few variations that take care of common cases (like `filterToLinkedList`)

Comment: @JudgeMental : true, would be nicer this way !